# Rejected edit of old question with an outdated URL

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7832386) the question [GADM-Maps cross-country comparision graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126745/gadm-maps-cross-country-comparision-graphics) because I found it when doing research for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862325/map-of-india-in-r-with-different-values-of-five-indicators-for-every-state-of-in), and noticed the URLs mentioned did not work anymore. To fix it, I found the updated URLs and replaced them in the code. I did one small change to the code because I was already there anyway.

The Edit Suggestion was rejected, and I assume it's because the new URL is from a completely different domain and the reviewers probably thought it was spam or trolling, but that's just how it is now at the [GADM website](http://www.gadm.org/download).

Or is there something wrong with updating this kind of information? The way it is now, the question isn't even reproducible (which is one of the things that led me to it). It's also worth mentioning that the accepted answer has the same outdated URL, which IMHO should be corrected.

**Edit**

I just thought a little bit more about this, and maybe the reviewers rejected the edit because I replaced one function of the code (`paste(..., sep=" ")`) with a wrapper for it (`paste0(...)`)? I understand it's not a good a idea to change question's codes, even if they don't change the overall result or context.

**Edit 2**

Thanks to the suggestions and insight provided at the answers here, I [resubmitted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7897180) the suggestion without the code change and with a better explanation of the URL correction, which was accepted. Now to the Answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Normally code changes of that magnitude are frowned upon and I wouldn't be surprised if people automatically reached for the *Reject* button.

Because you can only suggest edits, when fixing links make it very clear in your comment that you are fixing link rot.

I would also think twice about fixing links within a code section - ask yourself:

- are the actual links critical, or are they effectively decoration or noise?
- if the links are necessary, were they the cause of the bug?

If the bug was caused by the nature of the URLs or the resource they point to then changing them makes the question invalid. But if this is the case then you could also argue that a fundamental change in the target resources (like what has happened due to the website being changed) now makes the question a candidate for closure as it is off topic and no longer reproducible.

If the target resource has simply changed location but not changed in any other way then your fix would have been correct (assuming that the `paste0` change was also correct).

Comment: Thanks. I realize now I shouldn't have changed the code, but when I got to the question, it was actually a source of code for me, much more like an answer, and not something I would answer, which is why I ended up improving the code. Is it okay now if I suggest the edit again, this time without the code change problem?

Answer (score 6):

The `paste0` change would require that the reviewer would be fluent in R.  And it did not significantly improve the code.  I'd leave it out, or at least not roll it in.

The URL change: making it clear that the official URL had changed.  A link to the gadm website download (so it doesn't look like spam), a statement that the url had changed *long after the original poster put the url in* (so it wasn't the OP's problem), would help.

That second check requires work, but it is something you need to do anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the body of a question is approved for those edits that do not change the meaning of the original post, although we know you want to improve it.

The solution is to add a comment below the post to confirm the owner of the post and others.